# undefined is not a function (evaluating this.function() in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, parse-platform

So what I have is this:
I want to keep all the 'parse' code inside a manager that I can call from another classes and files. On this example I have a function that will only check if the user is logged in and then return different drawer navigations based on that. The problem is that I keep getting the error 'undefined is not a function (evaluating ...)'. Im kinda new to javascript and couldn't find an answer to this. Here's the code.

Thanks in advance.

### ParseManager.js

```
isUserLogged() {
Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        console.log("ParseManager - User logged in.")
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("ParseManager - User logged off.")
        return false;
    }
});
```

### App.js

```
render() {
if (ParseManager.isUserLogged()) {
  return (
    <SecondaryRoot />
  );
} else {
  return (
    <MainRoot />
  );
}
```

Comment: on which line??

Comment: post all the code, not only a part

Comment: ```isUserLogged``` is not doing what you think it's doing. It's returning ```undefined``` because ```Parse.User...``` is a promise.

Comment: @Wainage indeed it's returning undefined, how can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply call isUserLogged on component mount and later simply check the state:
ParseManager.js

```
isUserLogged(callback) {
   Parse.User.currentAsync().then(function (user) {
     if (user) {
         console.log("ParseManager - User logged in.")
         callback(true);
     } else {
         console.log("ParseManager - User logged off.")
         callback(false);
     }
});
```

App.js

```
componentDidMount(){
    ParseManager.isUserLogged(
       (logged)=>{
         this.setState({logged});});
       });
}

render() {
  if (this.state.logged) {
    return (
      <SecondaryRoot />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <MainRoot />
    );
  }
```